# Custom Post Type - Rewite Archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to figure out the following :

- I have a CPT called "Podcast" which has a slug as /podcasts/
- I have a Page called "Podcasts" which has a slug as /podcasts/

I want my single podcast posts to have a permalink of /podcasts/%podcast_category%/post_name

When i do this, I cannot edit the podcasts page, as wordpress displays the archive page instead. How can i modify my code, so the archive page has a different slug,  but still keeping /podcasts/%podcast_category%/post_name for single podcasts, and /podcasts/ can be used as a page.

```
//register podcast posts
function custom_post_podcasts_register(){

$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x('Podcast', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name'      => _x('Podcast', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new'            => _x('Add New', 'podcast'),
    'add_new_item'       => __('Add New Podcast'),
    'edit_item'          => __('Edit Podcast'),
    'new_item'           => __('New Integration'),
    'view_item'          => __('View Podcast'),
    'search_items'       => __('Search Podcast'),
    'not_found'          => __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon'  => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => true,
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'show_in_rest'       => true,
    'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'podcasts','with_front' => false),
    'has_archive'        => 'podcast-all',
    'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt','podcast_category', 'podcast_tags'),
    'taxonomies'         => array( 'podcast_category', 'podcast_tags' ),
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-format-quote',
    'has_archive'        => true
  ); 
register_post_type('podcast' , $args);
}
add_action('init', 'custom_post_podcasts_register');
add_filter('manage_edit-podcast_columns', 'admin_remove_columns');

//create a custom taxonomy name it "type" for your posts
function podcast_custom_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
  'name' => _x( 'Podcast Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
  'singular_name' => _x( 'podcast_category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
  'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Podcast Category' ), 
  'update_item' => __( 'Update Podcast Category' ),
  'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Podcast Category' ),
  'new_item_name' => __( 'New Podcast Category Name' ),
  'menu_name' => __( 'Podcast Category' ),
);  

register_taxonomy('podcast_category',array('podcast'), array(
  'labels'                     => $labels,
      'hierarchical'               => true,
      'public'                     => true,
      'show_ui'                    => true,
      'show_admin_column'          => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
      'show_tagcloud'              => true,
      'show_in_rest'               => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'podcast_category' ),
));
}
// Let us create Taxonomy for Custom Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'podcast_custom_taxonomy', 0 );

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function podcast_tags_taxononmy() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Podcast Tag',
    'singular_name'              => 'Podcast Tag',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Podcast Tags',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Podcast Tags',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Podcast Tag',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Podcast Tag:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Podcast Tag',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Podcast Tag',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Podcast Tag',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Podcast Tag',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Podcast Tags with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Podcast Tags',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Podcast Tags',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Podcast Tags',
    'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'show_in_rest'               => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'podcast-tags', array( 'podcast' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'podcast_tags_taxononmy', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that the Podcast Archive will have a different slug than the Podcast Page. Otherwise, WordPress won't know which resource to serve when the user visits `/podcasts/`.

Give the Taxonomy a default term. This ensures that every Podcast lands in a category and will have a category in the permalink. See [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) for full args.

```
register_taxonomy( 'podcast_category', array('podcast'), array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'podcasts-category' ),
    'default_term' => array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Uncategorized' ),
    ),
) );
```

Add an arbitrary placeholder in the Post Type rewrite slug.

```
register_post_type( 'podcast' , array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'       => 'podcasts/%podcast_category%',
        'with_front' => false
    ),
    'has_archive' => 'podcasts-all',
) );
```

Replace the arbitrary placeholder in the Postcast URL.

```
/**
 * Post Type Link
 * Replace placeholder with post term.
 *
 * @param String $post_link
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return String $post_link
 */
function podcast_post_link( $post_link, $post ) {

    if( 'podcast' !== $post_type ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'podcast_category' );

    if( ! ( empty( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) ) ) {
        $post_link = str_replace( '%podcast_category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'podcast_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

Save permalinks. Head to Settings > Permalinks and click Save. This will refresh the permalink structure. What you should end up with:

Podcast Page: `/podcasts/`
Podcast Archive: `/podcasts-all/`
Podcast Category: `/podcast-category/uncategorized/`
Podcast Singular: `/podcasts/uncategorized/podcast-slug/`

---

Note that in your `register_post_type()` you're calling `has_archive` twice. The 2nd `has_archive => true` is overwriting your post type archive slug.

Comment: Awesome. Actually the 2nd has_archive which i missed, was the culprit.